# Control punctuation after "ibid" in author-year citation

Tags: biblatex

I would like to have a colon as the delimiter between the year and the page number in an author-year footnote citation. But after the word "ibid" I would like to have a comma instead of a colon.

Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
autocite=footnote,
bibstyle=authoryear-ibid,
citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@book{book,
  title={Fabulous Book},
  author={Fred Smith},
  year={2006},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite[5]{book}
\autocite[6]{book}

\end{document}
```

Right now, it puts a colon after the word "ibid" because of the settings. Is there a way to make the delimiter a comma only after the word "ibid"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following construction.

We can't simply test for `\ifciteibid` in `postnotedelim`, because the citation tracker may already be in a different state when the postnote is finally printed. So we have to go via a helper toggle that we explicitly switch in each citation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  autocite=footnote,
]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{cbx:isibid}

\AtEveryCitekey{\global\togglefalse{cbx:isibid}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:isibid}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}

\DeclareDelimFormat*{postnotedelim}{%
  \iftoggle{cbx:isibid}
    {\addcomma}
    {\addcolon}%
  \space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocites[5]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocites[6]{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocites[5]{nussbaum}
sit \autocites[6]{sigfridsson}
amet \autocites[6]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998: 5.//2 Ibid., 6.]

Comment: This worked! Thank you. One additional follow-up question: in order for me to make it work, I had to add in an extra # in two places, resulting in the code below. Do you know why that is the case?    

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{##1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{##1}}

Comment: @classicsbro Mhh, in the example you definitely don't need doubled hashes. Doubled hashes are only needed to refer to arguments if you nest your macro definition (in this case `\DeclareFieldFormat`) inside another macro definition. This isn't the case in this example. Maybe it is the case in your real-world example or maybe this is just the symptom of a forgotten curly brace or a similar syntax error.

Comment: That makes sense. In the MWE I un-nested my commands, but in my "real" document, this is all nested inside other commands that I can use to switch to a different kind of bibliography when needed, thus the need for the second hash. Thanks again for all the help.